# Ensuring effect to GKE which run for Cloud-Composer from upgrading to v1.23 of GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I have some cloud composer.

Is upgrading to v1.23 of GKE effect to cloud composer?
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/webhookcompatibility

Although I inspected backend service which has possibility to be impact, I thought no exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not upgrade GKE clusters** **in your Cloud Composer environment to a newer version unless specifically stated in the [Cloud Composer Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes) or the [Known Issues page](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/known-issues) .** Use the GKE version that was preconfigured when you created the environment and take advantage of the automatic upgrade of the GKE Service.

All existing Cloud Composer's GKE clusters will be **auto-upgraded to newer GKE versions** with a fix for the issues described in [CVE-2021-25741](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/security-bulletins#gcp-2022-011). New GKE versions are released [regularly](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes), but a version is not selected for auto-upgrade right away. When a GKE version has acquired enough cluster usage to prove stability over time, Google selects it as an auto-upgrade target for clusters running a subset of older versions.New auto-upgrade targets are announced in the release notes.

The recommended best practice that is suggested would be to take advantage of the **automatic upgrade** provided by GKE Service, so the cluster version and composer version will be in sync which avoids [incompatibility issues.](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/known-issues#announcements_about_the_removal_of_support_for_deprecated_beta_apis_from_versions)